# Lock Variable not changing

Tags: python

```py
#Pass Lock
password = 2412
unlock = False

passwordT = input("Input Pass")

if passwordT == password:
    unlock = True

print(unlock)
```

Why does the unlock variable not change to True when input is correct?

Comment: `password` is integer. `input()` returns a string. try to think about solution.

Comment: Please share the research you carried out before posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

Because `input()` returns a string, and `password`'s value is an integer and for sanity's sake, comparing strings and integers won't implicitly convert either of them (like might happen in PHP or JavaScript):

```
>>> "2412" == 2412
False
>>> 2412 == "2412"
False
>>>
```

Either:

- Make `password` a string: `password = "2412"`
- Convert the user input to an integer (with the caveat that conversion could fail if the user enters e.g. `foo`): `passwordT = int(input(...))`

Answer (score 0):

input() in python takes the user input as a string. since you are checking an Integer with a string the `unlock` variable won't be changed to `True`. You should either change the password to String - `password = "2412"` or convert the input into int -`passwordT = int(input("Input Pass"))`